# spring-batch in @Scheduled is overloading

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

I have a @Scheduled annotation and inside i'm calling a batch task, like:

```
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
```

So, my scheduler is setup `initialDelay = 5000`, `fixedDelay=5000`.

The problem is that, after **5000 miliseconds**, the schedule is running again before the first ending. Is overloading.

Exist some way to make it wait to execute again before the first finished ?

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with Spring Scheduler.  I know Quartz has the concept of a stateful Job that won't fire if there is one already running.

Comment: Can you add some more configuration? I quickly validated, i don't see this behavior, instead the behavior described in doc which is what you are looking for